# what's these theads named after http-8080 for?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, web

in every Spring mvc app, every time i open a browser window to access the server, there will start some threads named like 'thread-8080-1'.
[image: http threads]

even i did not click any action or url, these threads keep themselves alive. What's them for? Long pooling or sth?

Comment: You can use jconsole (it comes with your Oracle JDK bundle) and see the stack trace for this particular thread. Maybe it can get you a hint.

Comment: @JeandersonBarrosCândido debugger in eclipse has the same functionalities. but it is not easy to figure it out.

Comment: What web server are you using? Tomcat? Jetty?

Comment: @Andreas it's an embedded tomcat in maven.

Comment: They're servlet threads.

Comment: @Andreas will they keep alive as long as the browser window opens? any docs on it? thx!

Comment: Tomcat doesn't know if you have a browser window open. I believe those are request processing threads, for handling requests coming in on port 8080. It's a thread pool, with an apparent minimum size of 3 threads.